# Cast from 'NSData' to unrelated type 'NSHTTPURLResponse' always fails

Tags: swift, casting, nsdata, httpresponse, nshttpurlresponse

I have this code :

```
let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in

            guard let response = data else {
                print("Error: did not receive data")
                return
            }

            guard error == nil else {
                print("error")
                print(error)
                return
            }

            let httpResponse = response as! NSHTTPURLResponse
            let statusCode = httpResponse.statusCode

            if (statusCode == 200) {
                print("OK!!!")
            }
        })

        task.resume()
```

At the line : `let httpResponse = response as! NSHTTPURLResponse` I have this strange warning : `Cast from 'NSData' to unrelated type 'NSHTTPURLResponse' always fails`

How should I get rid of it ? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are unwrapping the content of `data` in a constant called `response`. It's the source of your issue, because then you are using one thinking you are using the other.

Also, why force unwrapping the downcast?

It's better to continue using `guard` like you already do.

Example:

```
let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in

    guard let data = data else {
        print("Error: did not receive data")
        return
    }

    guard error == nil else {
        print("error")
        print(error)
        return
    }

    guard let httpResponse = response as? NSHTTPURLResponse else {
        print("response unavailable")
        return
    }

    let statusCode = httpResponse.statusCode

    if statusCode == 200 {
        print("OK!!!")
    }
})

task.resume()
```

Comment: Thanks this kinda fix it, but it gives me another warning on line : guard let data = data else { ; the warning is :  Immutable value 'data' was never used; consider replacing with '_' or removing it ... PS: Sorry a novice!!!

Comment: The compiler is just telling you that you unwrap `data` but you don't use it - which is true. You can silence the warning by replacing `guard let data = data` with `guard let _ = data` if you don't use `data` at all in this task.

Comment: Thanks alot for the help and explanation!